# Loading of somefile.xml: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 11

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm trying to import an XML file but there is a character that is not not being accepted by PHP.

The only non-standard characters I am seeing are the @ symbol and some encoded characters `&lt;` for < `&gt;` for > and `&amp;` for &.  Does XML have a hard time understanding any of these?

Answer (score 1):

In an XML document you should always encode the following characters to ensure a proper parsing:

- < should be encoded as `&lt;`
- > should be encoded as `&gt;`
- & should be encoded as `&amp;`
- ' should be encoded as `&#39;`
- " should be encoded as `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check whether the XML header of the document indicates

```
<?xml version="1.1" ?>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

The former supports a [wider character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML) than the latter. But remember that `char(0)` is always invalid.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20805244) from user keshlam.