# SimpleXML in php set the xml validation restriction

Tags: php, xml, validation, simplexml

I am looking for a XML parser in PHP where we can set the restriction level on the XML validation. Basically I wanted to set the XML parser in such a way that parser does not validate the values and it just validates the Tags. I tried `SimpleXML` / `DOM` I wasn't able to find.

More Info.

for eg:

```
<XMLtag1>
   <XMlTag2>&amp;#1;&amp;#1;&amp;#1;&amp;#1;&amp;#1;/XMlTag2>
   <XMlTag3>&amp;#1;&amp;#1;&amp;#1;&amp;#1;&amp;</XMlTag3>
   <XMlTag3>`Rb&amp;#3;&amp;#3;</XMlTag3>
</XMLtag1>
```

In the above XML parsers will validate the values and it can give some errors like `xmlParseCharRef`  i want to avoid this.

**More Clarity on My issue**.

I got a XML file which when am trying to parse it am getting an error described as in the stackoverflow question here

> [XML encoding setup and specific charsets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19961421/782145)

The Answer given over there is not satisfactory for me.  so here actually you can see that the XML parser is trying to decode the &#xx formats. I don't want that.

Any Help?
Thanks 
Philip.

Comment: Not sure I get it. Could you please *edit* the question and provide an example of invalid XML that you want your validator to ignore?

Comment: You could define your own parser and its rules - http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario : Added more details in the Question.

Comment: I don't get it. Your example is invalid only because you are missing a `<` in `</XMlTag2>`. Add that in, and [SimpleXML parses it without issuing any errors at all](http://3v4l.org/jWUEJ). I have no idea what it would mean to "validate the values".

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. If you want a validator that doesn't warn about malformed XML and doesn't validate actual values (as in "complies with a given XML schema"), what do you want to validate? You could just write a one-liner: `function isValid($xml){ return true; }`. Do you by chance just want to consume some invalid XML you have?

Comment: If I understand it right, your example doesn't actually reproduce your problem, because you've double-escaped the `&` signs as `&amp;`. It's always a good idea when creating dummy data or code to test it, so that you know other people will actually see the problem you're expecting them to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML/DOM do only validate that the document is well formed - that the XML syntax is correct. Advanced validations can be done with DOM.

- `DOMDocument::validate()` validates the current document against the defined DTD
- `DOMDocument::schemaValidate[Source]()` validate against a given Schema
- `DOMDocument::relaxNGValidate[Source]()` validate against a given RelaxNG

Which elements, attributes and values are allowed are defined be the DTD/Schema/RelaxNG.

An XML document has to be well formed. That is not a question of validation but that the parser can not read the XML if it contains fatal syntax errors. Not all syntax errors are fatal, some can be ignored if you're fine with the result.

If the XML contains fatal syntax errors, you will have to use string functions or regular expressions to repair them.